# MonoX cms installation process

Tags: content-management-system, social-networking

Hi: I need help regarding monox installation process . i followed the user manual but unable to install the portal. if any one have idea kindly guide me through installation of monox. Thanks in advance.[image: I don't know what i am doing wrong i get this service not available]

Comment: Hi Bilal, as I have explained on our support forum you don't have any issues with MonoX installation but rather with the ASP.NET as it's not registered inside the IIS. Please try to follow the ASP.NET IIS registration process as I have explained and get back to us if you have any issues (reply on MonoX support forum).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have MonoX installation problem but issue with IIS and ASP.NET as ASP.NET it's not registered inside the IIS.

You can register ASP.NET in IIS manually by following instructions from the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.140).aspx) or you can use [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) where you need to search for 'register' and you will get the two packages listed named *Execute ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool* and you should install both of them.

After you install and register the ASP.NET in IIS you should restart the IIS Manager and IIS and try again.